# Error trying to upload pictures on Heroku web app with AS3 (works in production) Michael Hartl Chap 11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, railstutorial.org

I am doing the Michael Hartl tutorial. chapter 11.

My app uploads pictures in productions but not when I deploy it, yet the text microposts do work, so the problem is somewhere with Amazon S3

I have set the permissions on S3 to "everyone" to upload/delete on my bucket.

I have set the right S3 keys on my heroku account using the rails console to not have them in the code (as the tutorial recommends).

Here is a copy of the error message when I try to upload something on my web app:

```
2014-11-07T10:25:23.192777+00:00 app[web.1]:    (2.2ms)  BEGIN
2014-11-07T10:25:23.198717+00:00 app[web.1]:   SQL (2.1ms)  INSERT INTO "microposts" ("content", "created_at", "picture", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["content", "Wont work "], ["created_at", "2014-11-07 10:25:23.194942"], ["picture", "BALI_BLOG.jpg"], ["updated_at", "2014-11-07 10:25:23.194942"], ["user_id", 101]]
2014-11-07T10:25:28.198243+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/microposts" host=cryptic-falls-5768.herokuapp.com request_id=eb6bfb98-4146-4268-aaec-817aa15c7e51 fwd="114.129.16.105" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6
632ms status=500 bytes=1786
2014-11-07T10:25:28.195098+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5613ms
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197697+00:00 app[web.1]: excon.error.response
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197714+00:00 app[web.1]:     "x-amz-request-id" => "75844FA2260D74EC"
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197695+00:00 app[web.1]: Excon::Errors::Forbidden (Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197712+00:00 app[web.1]:     "x-amz-id-2"       => "9Lm1JyP7J8nLkOhAo0eXtlmoaR2bBf+tJj6z0WZWApxAiRO1n7gCwWtWer5LrkH8RLCKf4K4Eg4="
2014-11-07T10:25:28.193952+00:00 app[web.1]:    (2.1ms)  ROLLBACK
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197715+00:00 app[web.1]:   }
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197717+00:00 app[web.1]:   :local_address => "172.18.66.78"
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197718+00:00 app[web.1]:   :local_port    => 22004
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197720+00:00 app[web.1]:   :reason_phrase => "Forbidden"
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197721+00:00 app[web.1]:   :remote_ip     => "54.231.242.81"
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197723+00:00 app[web.1]:   :status        => 403
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197724+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197706+00:00 app[web.1]:     "Connection"       => "close"
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197725+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:7:in `create'
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197708+00:00 app[web.1]:     "Content-Type"     => "application/xml"
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197727+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197711+00:00 app[web.1]:     "Server"           => "AmazonS3"
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197728+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197692+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197703+00:00 app[web.1]:   :body          => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>75844FA2260D74EC</RequestId><HostId>9Lm1JyP7J8nLkOhAo0eXtlmoaR2bBf+tJj6z0WZWApxAiRO1n7gCwWtWer5LrkH8RLCKf4K4Eg4=</HostId></Error>"
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197705+00:00 app[web.1]:   :headers       => {
2014-11-07T10:25:28.197709+00:00 app[web.1]:     "Date"             => "Fri, 07 Nov 2014 10:25:27 GMT"
```

Also, here is the code in relevant files :

/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb

```
if Rails.env.production?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
      # Configuration for Amazon S3
      :provider              => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
      :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY'],
      :region  => ENV['S3_REGION']
    }
    config.fog_directory     =  ENV['S3_BUCKET']
  end
end
```

congig/environments/production

```
    Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or NGINX will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
   config.force_ssl = true

  # Decrease the log volume.
  # config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'cryptic-falls-5768.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
   }
  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

I am much of a noob with this, it is my first real deployed web application and first time using S3 but I followed every step precisely and after typing, verified my code was copy/paste identical to the tutorial.

Please let me know if there is any additional code I can provide to help solve the problem.

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer helpful. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28465489

You need to attach amazons3fullaccess policy to the user.

When setting up the IAM user the amazon walkthrough tells you to attach a policy to the bucket itself. The example they give just includes a putobject and getobject actions for the bucket. But i think uploading requires permissions for lots of actions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by changing the initializer filename to carrierwave.rb instead of carrier_wave.rb

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I think it's a permissions problem, and it seems your log is saying the same. Look on the IAM dashboard on your AWS console. Make sure the user is a member of a group, and that the same group has admin level permissions. This fixed it for me!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It turned out to be the names of the Amazon regions, they are a bit tricky. My bucket is listed as "Ireland" in the AWS interface but it must be referred to as 'eu-west-1' from Rails/Heroku.